# using Jordan's Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

Is this the right way to use Jordan's Lemma to show that integration over the semi-circle does not contribute to the closed-contour integration for the integral $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x \sin (7x)}{(x^2-6x+18)} dx$

$$\text{Im}\left(\oint_C \frac{z e^{i7z}}{z^2-6z+18}dz\right) 
= \text{Im}\left(\oint_C \frac{Re^{ix} }{R^2e^{2ix}-6e^{ix}+18}dz\right)
= \text{Im}\left(\oint_C \frac{R}{R^2e-6R+18}dz\right)
$$

Comment: No, the part of the contour integral coming from the semi-circle is

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{Re^{it}e^{i7Re^{it}}\cdot iRe^{it}}{(Re^{it})^2 -6Re^{it} + 18}\,dt.$$

Answer (score 0):

What does Jordan's lemma say?

> If $f(z$) is analytic in the upper half-plane except for a finite number of poles in $\operatorname{Im} z \geq 0$, and if the maximum of $|f(z)|$ vanishes as $|z| \to \infty$ in the upper half-plane, then 
>   $$ 
> I_{\Gamma} = \int_{\Gamma} e^{imz} f(z)\ dz \to 0 \quad \mbox{as} \quad R \to \infty \\
> \mbox{where}\ \Gamma \ \mbox{is the contour over our semi-circle.}
> $$

Is our $f(z) = \frac{z}{z^2-6z+18}$ analytic in the upper half-plane, except for a finite number of poles? And do we have that the maximum of $|f(z)| \to 0$ as $|z| \to \infty$?